# What's the difference between "Default scope" and "BundleDefaultsScope" among Eclipse Preference scope?

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse Preference scope, I have read this
[article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html) and learned something. Then I went to read some code and found something that was confusing to me.

In `org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.AntUIPreferenceInitializer`, use `BundleDefaultsScope` :

```java
IPreferenceStore prefs = AntUIPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
prefs.setDefault(IAntUIPreferenceConstants.ANT_FIND_BUILD_FILE_NAMES, "build.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

In `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEPreferenceInitializer`, use `Default scope`:

```java
IEclipsePreferences node = DefaultScope.INSTANCE.getNode(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getBundle().getSymbolicName());
```

Why? What's the difference? What could be the purpose of such a design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Default Scope` cannot be persisted and the default value cannot be changed.  The default value is usually defined by program or product.  Such as `org.eclipse.platform/plugin_customization.ini`

`BundleDefaults Scope` cannot be persisted but is allowed to change, it's just more used for setting the default preference value, Usually it is used with `Plugin.getPreferenceStore().setDefault` .

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences
org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.BundleDefaultPreferences
```

Answer (score 1):

`IPreferenceStore` is a layer on top of`IEclipsePreference`. It provides a single interface to the instance and default preference scopes. It can also be used for more complicated things using multiple stores (the Ant example is actually one of them using Ants own `OverlayPreferenceStore`).

Usually `IPreferenceStore` uses the `ScopedPreferenceStore` implementation.

ScopedPreferenceStore usually uses a `InstanceScope` and a `DefaultScope` for a plug-in (Bundle) but can be set up with other scopes.

`IPreferenceStore.setDefault` ends up calling the `DefaultScope` `put` method (and `set` calls the `InstanceScope` `put`)